# IMemoryCache Feature or bug? Cache expiring unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net-core, caching

IMemoryCache Feature or bug?

In .net 6 I did some basic testing with IMemoryCache

In my example below

- PersonAsync works as expected after 1 second it expires and fetchs a new value from FetchPersonAsync
- PlaceAsync works as expected after 5 seconds it expires and feachs a new value from
  FetchPlaceAsync
- MixedAsync does not work as I would expect. after 1 second it expires and feachs a new value from FetchMixedAsync

In this case MixedAsync is set to expire after 60 seconds and calls PersonAsync and FetchAsync to build a value. But IMemoryCache seems to have determiend that due to my result of MixedAsync using data results from PersonAsync it will expire after 1 second.

Is this this a feature of IMemoryCache (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory)?

```
public class Query
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _memoryCache;

    public Query(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        _memoryCache = memoryCache;
    }

    public async Task<Person> PersonAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _memoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync
        (
            "PERSON",
            cacheEntry => {
                cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
                return FetchPersonAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task<Place> PlaceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _memoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync
        (
            "PLACE", 
            cacheEntry => {
                cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                return FetchPlaceAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task<Mixed> MixedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _memoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync
        (
            "MIXED",
            cacheEntry => {
                cacheEntry.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
                return FetchMixedAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
        ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

  
    internal async Task<Person> FetchPersonAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        return new Person
        {
            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };
    }

    internal async Task<Place> FetchPlaceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        return new Place
        {
            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };
    }

    internal async Task<Mixed> FetchMixedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var person = await PersonAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var place = await PlaceAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return new Mixed
        {
           BaseLineName = person.Name,
           FacetName = place.Name,
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Is this this a feature of IMemoryCache"_ - no, it is not.

Comment: Is this only for the second fetch or for many fetches?

Comment: for many fetchs. I rewrote a slightly more simple here that show cases it. https://dotnetfiddle.net/KWnMgN

Comment: At this point I just put a bug on github for MS and I’ll see how they respond. Ty for confirming that this is not what the end user expects. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/72345

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this this a feature of IMemoryCache (Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory)?

Sigh. Yes, technically, sort of. It's completely undocumented AFAIK. The feature is called ["linked cache entries"](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/45592#issue-757098814). (Note that the code you posted here does *not* exhibit that behavior, but the code posted in the .NET Fiddle does).

Linked cache entries are annoying enough (confusing - by my estimation - 100% of the devs who have encountered it), that .NET 7 is [making cache entries unlinked by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.memorycacheoptions.tracklinkedcacheentries?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058).

In the meantime, you can "break" the cache entry links by creating your own `IMemoryCache` implementation that wraps `MemoryCache` but returns [`SafeCacheEntry` wrappers](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/39a2cd0aa3c705a984a4dbbea8275fe9#file-asynccache-cs-L199) around the `MemoryCache`'s `ICacheEntry` instances.

Something like this should work (untested):

```
class MyMemoryCache : IMemoryCache
{
    private readonly MemoryCache _cache;    
    public MyMemoryCache(IOptions<MemoryCacheOptions> options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) =>
        _cache = new(options, loggerFactory);
    
    public ICacheEntry CreateEntry(object key) => SafeCacheEntry.Create(_cache, key);
    public void Dispose() => _cache.Dispose();
    public void Remove(object key) => _cache.Remove(key);
    public bool TryGetValue(object key, out object value) => _cache.TryGetValue(key, value);

    private sealed class SafeCacheEntry : ICacheEntry
    {
        private readonly ICacheEntry _cacheEntryImplementation;

        private SafeCacheEntry(ICacheEntry cacheEntryImplementation) => _cacheEntryImplementation = cacheEntryImplementation;

        public static ICacheEntry Create(IMemoryCache cache, object key)
        {
            return AsyncCreateEntry().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

#pragma warning disable 1998
            async Task<ICacheEntry> AsyncCreateEntry() => new SafeCacheEntry(cache.CreateEntry(key));
#pragma warning restore 1998
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            AsyncDispose().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

#pragma warning disable 1998
            async Task AsyncDispose() => _cacheEntryImplementation.Dispose();
#pragma warning restore 1998
        }

        public object Key => _cacheEntryImplementation.Key;

        public object Value
        {
            get => _cacheEntryImplementation.Value;
            set => _cacheEntryImplementation.Value = value;
        }

        public DateTimeOffset? AbsoluteExpiration
        {
            get => _cacheEntryImplementation.AbsoluteExpiration;
            set => _cacheEntryImplementation.AbsoluteExpiration = value;
        }

        public TimeSpan? AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow
        {
            get => _cacheEntryImplementation.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow;
            set => _cacheEntryImplementation.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = value;
        }

        public TimeSpan? SlidingExpiration
        {
            get => _cacheEntryImplementation.SlidingExpiration;
            set => _cacheEntryImplementation.SlidingExpiration = value;
        }

        public IList<IChangeToken> ExpirationTokens => _cacheEntryImplementation.ExpirationTokens;

        public IList<PostEvictionCallbackRegistration> PostEvictionCallbacks => _cacheEntryImplementation.PostEvictionCallbacks;

        public CacheItemPriority Priority
        {
            get => _cacheEntryImplementation.Priority;
            set => _cacheEntryImplementation.Priority = value;
        }

        public long? Size
        {
            get => _cacheEntryImplementation.Size;
            set => _cacheEntryImplementation.Size = value;
        }
    }
}
```